# PureScript FFI to mocha

Tags: mocha.js, monads, ffi, purescript

I am trying to write mocha bindings into PureScript and am completely baffled by `Control.Monad.Eff`

```
describe(function(){
  //do stuff  
});
```

Describe is a function that takes nothing and returns IO, or Eff or something that means (side-effect happened no value returned).

---

My attempts so far

```
foreign import describe 
  "function describe(n){         \
  \ return function(){           \
  \   window.describe(n); \
  \ };                           \  
  \}" :: forall eff a. Eff eff a -> Eff eff

foreign import describe "describe" :: forall eff a. Eff eff a -> Eff eff
foreign import describe "describe" :: Eff -> Eff
foreign import describe "describe" :: forall eff a. (a -> Eff eff) -> Eff eff
```

Clearly missing something here. Please help.

Comment: Is this question about Haskell at all (apart from Purescript being written in it)? It'd probably be better to avoid the `haskell` tag if not, as it's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The foreign function interface of PureScript is actually very simple. For example suppose you have the following JavaScript function:

```
function si(p) {
    return function (r) {
        return function (t) {
            return p * r * t / 100;
        };
    };
}
```

You could import it as follows:

```
foreign import si :: Number -> Number -> Number -> Number
```

You could also inline the function as follows:

```
foreign import si
    "function si(p) {\
    \    return function (r) {\
    \        return function (t) {\
    \            return p * r * t / 100;\
    \        };\
    \    };\
    \}" :: Number -> Number -> Number -> Number
```

For side effects PureScript doesn't use the `IO` monad. Instead it makes use of the `Eff` monad.

From what I understand the `Eff` monad is the same as the `IO` monad with an extra type parameter: a row of effects.

For example, in Haskell the `print` function has the following type:

```
print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
```

In PureScript the `print` function has the following type:

```
print :: Show a => a -> Eff (trace :: Trace | r) Unit
```

So what do we understand from this?

1. `IO` is similar to `Eff e` where `e` is a row of effects.
2. `Unit` is similar to `()`.
3. The `print` function has the `trace` effect which is of the type `Trace`.
4. In addition, the `print` function can be combined with an other effect. Row polymorphism. This means that it is composable.

An `Eff` value by itself is called an action. For example `print "Hello World!"` which is of the type `Eff (trace :: Trace | r) Unit` is an action.

An `Eff` value which is an argument to a function is called a handler. It can be thought of as a higher-order effectful function with no parameters.

An `Eff` value with no side-effects is known as a pure value:

```
type Pure a = forall e. Eff e a
runPure :: Pure a -> a
```

Since the row of effects (i.e. `e`) is polymorphic (or in other words empty, a black hole), PureScript assumes that the function has no side-effects. However it also means that it can be composed with other effectful functions.

The `Eff` monad is a contract between the programmer and the compiler in which the programmer promises the compiler that the given `Eff` value will only have the stated row of effects and no more.

---

Coming to your `describe` function:

> Describe is a function that takes nothing and returns IO, or Eff or something that means (side-effect happened no value returned).

Actually this is wrong. Your `describe` function does take a function as an argument:

```
describe(function(){
  //do stuff
});
```

In addition the function that it takes has no arguments, which means that it is an effectful function. Hence it must be of the type `Eff e a` where `e` and `a` can be any row of effects and any return value respectively.

Thus your describe function must be of the type:

```
describe :: Eff e a -> Eff (describe :: Describe | e) {}
```

In Haskell it would be written as follows:

```
describe :: IO a -> IO ()
```

PureScript is just more explicit than Haskell. Anyway, `Describe` is a new effect type that you create which distinguishes it from other effect types such as `Trace`:

```
foreign import data Describe :: !
```

You would then import `describe` as follows:

```
foreign import describe
    "function describe(f) {\
    \    return function () {\
    \        window.describe(f);\
    \    };\
    \}" :: forall e a. Eff e a -> Eff (describe :: Describe | e) {}
```

Finally you can use it as follows:

```
main = do
    describe $ print "Hello World!"
```

The entire code is as follows:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Eff
import Debug.Trace

foreign import data Describe :: !

foreign import describe
    "function describe(f) {\
    \    return function () {\
    \        window.describe(f);\
    \    };\
    \}" :: forall e a. Eff e a -> Eff (describe :: Describe | e) {}

main = do
    describe $ print "Hello World!"
```

It would produce the following JavaScript:

```
var PS = PS || {};

PS.Main = (function () {
    "use strict";

    var Prelude = PS.Prelude;
    var Debug_Trace = PS.Debug_Trace;

    function describe(f) {
        return function () {
            window.describe(f);
        };
    }

    var print = Debug_Trace.print(Prelude.showString({})); 

    var main = describe(print("Hello World!"));

    return {
        main: main, 
        describe: describe
    };
}());
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That was extremely helpful. But I am still not quite understanding a few things. I understand the Haskell version, but the purescript still confuses me. Why is `forall` necessary? What is the `| e)` mean in the record? Why is the record followed with `{}`?

Comment: Your response is amazing, I'm accepting it regardless. Thank you.

Comment: The `forall` in Haskell is implicit, which means that you don't need to type it. Hence in Haskell if you type `foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a` the compiler assumes that it means `foldl :: forall a b. (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a`. However in PureScript the `forall` is explicit which means that you always have to type it or else the compiler will generate an error. It's ugly, but it's still ok.

Comment: The type `forall e. { a :: A, b :: B | e }` means "match an object with the properties `a :: A` and `b :: B`, __and any other properties__". This is necessary because an object may have additional properties. If we only wrote `{ a :: A, b :: B }` then the compiler would assume that the object only had the properties `a :: A` and `b :: B` and nothing else. This means that if the object had additional properties then the compiler would throw an error. Adding the extra `| e` at the end tells the compiler that it's okay for the object to have additional properties. Also enables merging of objects.

Comment: The kind signature of the `Eff` monad is `Eff :: # ! -> * -> *`. This means that the first parameter is a __row__ (denoted by `#`) of __effects__ (denoted by `!`). The second parameter is any pure (i.e. non-effectful) value (denoted by `*`). The result is also a pure value. Hence the `Eff` monad requires two parameters: a row of effect types and a return type. The type of your `describe` function is `Eff e a -> Eff (describe :: Describe | e) {}`. This means that the argument can have any number of effects and return any value. The return type adds a new effect and returns an empty object value

Comment: You rock. This all makes sense now. Can wait to get home and play with this. Hopefully I can publish `mocha` `chai` and `sinon` bindings.

Comment: I would only make the following small modification: since the Mocha docs seem to indicate that calls to `describe` can be nested, you might want the following type signature:

`forall e a. Eff (describe :: Describe | e) a -> Eff (describe :: Describe | e) Unit`

Comment: @PhilFreeman That would be problematic because then the compiler would expect every function passed to `describe` to have the `Describe` effect. This would mean that expressions like `describe $ print "Hello World!"` would be illegal because `print "Hello World!"` does not have the `Describe` effect. It only has the `Trace` effect. On the other hand `Eff e a` is generic. The polymorphic row of effects `e` means that it could have any effects including the `Describe` effect. The return value is `e` plus the `Describe` effect. If `Describe` is already in `e` then it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @AaditMShah Not true. `print "Hello World"` has a polymorphic type, which can be specialised to `Eff (trace :: Trace, describe :: Describe) Unit`

Comment: @PhilFreeman I stand corrected. I tried compiling `describe $ describe $ print "Hello World!"` using both your method and my method at http://try.purescript.org and it works either way. So it doesn't really make a difference whether we use `Eff e a` or `Eff (describe :: Describe | e) a`.

Comment: I like the way this answer embeds Javascript right into the Purescript file but I don't see that documented anywhere and I couldn't get it to work. I'm using Purescript 11, and it's four years later 2018. Is this syntax no longer supported?

Comment: @Winston I wouldn't know because I don't use PureScript. However, you can ask Phil Freeman (read the comments above). He's the original author of PureScript.